# Proper usage of javascript in developing a website using wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm not sure what seems to be the problem.. I've used get_template_directory(); and bloginfo(); properly.. Working perfectly as they are.. but the problem is.. the javascript isn't working.. I'm not sure if I have to add get_template_directory_uri to every javascript calls. Any help would be appreciated

```
header.php
```

```
    <head>
    <title>Blank</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mr+De+Haviland|Yanone+Kaffeesatz:400,700|Open+Sans:400italic,400,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <!-- INLUDING STYLES -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />


    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url')?>" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/poshytip-1.0/src/tip-twitter/tip-twitter.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/mosaic.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>

<body>
<!-- TOP PART -->
    <div id="banner-bg">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html" title="Emporium"><a href="index.html" title="One Excelsia"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/OneExcelsiaFinal.png" alt="Unix Logo" name="logo" width="960" height="538" id="logo" class="img-responsive"/></a></a>
    </div>
    <!-- end logo --> 
  </div>
  <!-- end container --> 
</div>
<!-- end topContainer --> 
<!-- MENNU -->
<div id="menuContainer">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div id="mainmenu" class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
      <ul class="sf-menu hidden-xs">
        <li><a href="index.html" id="visited">Home</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index1.html">Piecemaker</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio Three Columns</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio.html">Circle Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio.html">Project Detail Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="singleblog.html">Single Blog Post</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Features</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Columns</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Price table</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- end mainmenu -->
    <div id="socialsContainer" class="col-md-6 hidden-xs">
      <div class="effect1 fl hidden-xs"> <a href="#" id="hovereffect1">Socialize</a> </div>
      <ul class="socials fr">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/socials/twitter.png" class="poshytip" title="Twitter" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/socials/facebook.png" class="poshytip" title="Facebook" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/socials/dribbble.png" class="poshytip" title="Dribbble" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/socials/google%20plus.png" class="poshytip" title="Forrst" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/socials/deviant.png" class="poshytip" title="Deviantart" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/socials/deviant.png" class="poshytip" title="Kiko" alt="" /></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- end socials --> 
  <!-- end container --> 
</div>
</div>
</div>


footer.php
<div class="blankSeparator2"><!-- --></div>

<!-- end bottomPart --> 
<!-- end MAIN --> 
<!-- FOOTER -->
<div id="footerContainer">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="footer" class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <h3>One Excelsia </h3>
        <p>Online Staffing &amp; Internet Marketing</p>
        <p>Executive Assistants, Internet Marketing Staff, Web Developers &amp; Designers</p>
      </div>
      <!-- end onethird -->
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <div id="flickrContainer">
          <h3>Flickr Gallery</h3>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><img src="img/flickr1.png" alt=""/> </li>
            <li><img src="img/flickr2.png" alt=""/> </li>
            <li><img src="img/flickr3.png" alt=""/> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- end flickrContainer --> 
      </div>
      <!-- end one-third -->
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <div id="twitter">
          <h3>Latest Tweets</h3>
          <div id="tweets"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- end twitter --> 
      </div>
      <!-- end one-third lastCol --> 
    </div>
    <!-- end fotter --> 
  </div>
  <!-- end container --> 
</div>
<!-- end footerContainer --> 

<!-- BOTTOM --> 
<!-- Footer Copyright Container -->
<div id="footerCopyrightContainer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="fl">&copy; Copyright 2012 &quot;Emporium&quot; by <a href="http://www.anarieldesign.com/">Anariel Design</a>. All rights reserved.</p>
    <a class="totop" href="#top"><img src="img/totop.png" class="poshytip" title="back to top" alt=""/></a> </div>
  <!-- end container --> 
</div>
<!-- end footerCopyrightContainer --> 
<!-- END BOTTOM -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/holder.js"></script>


    <!-- INLUDING SCRIPTS -->
    <!-- Include jQuery  -->

    <!-- Include main functions -->
    <script src="js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Tooltip -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/poshytip-1.0/src/jquery.poshytip.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Mosaic jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mosaic.1.0.1.js"></script>
    <!-- Tweets -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.tweetable.js'></script>
    <!-- Lettering -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lettering.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.hoverwords.js"></script>
    <!-- Piecemaker -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src='scripts/swfobject/swfobject.js'></script>
    <!-- Nivo slider -->
    <script src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Include Superfish -->
    <script src="js/superfish.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Include prettyPhoto -->
    <script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "javascript isn't working"?

Comment: I have a span element with a javascript hover behavior..

Comment: @user3064038 Make sure that your javascript files are included properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript files are not included properly that should be like :

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

like you have used to include the CSS files.

The proper way to include CSS and JS file is, create the following function in your functions.php file:

```
function include897_script_style(){
    // For Styles
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', 
                       get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/mosaic.css' );

    // for Scripts
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', 
                        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', 
                        array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include897_script_style');
```

for more information take a look on [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)